# How to execute function with completion handler sequentially?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, synchronization, wkwebview

I have a Swift function `fillField` that uses JavaScript injection to fill form fields in a WKWebView based on given CSS selectors. The JS function returns the number of filed fields. I would like to modify the Swift function so that it tries each selector sequentially, and if one of the selectors successfully fills a field (or multiple fields), the function should return early without attempting the remaining selectors.

For example, the functions is triggered with:

```swift
fillField(in: webView, selectors: ["input[autocomplete=\"username\"]", "input[name=\"username\" i]"], value: "test_value") { fills in
    console.debug("Auto-filled \(fills) fields")
}
```

Here is the existing code for the fillField function:

```
private func fillField(in webView: WKWebView, selectors: [String], value: String? = nil, checked: Bool? = nil, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    for selector in selectors {
        let script: String
        if let value = value {
            script = String(format: "AutoFill.setValue(\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\')", selector, "value", value)
        } else if let checked = checked {
            script = String(format: "AutoFill.setValue(\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\')", selector, "checked", checked ? "true": "false")
        } else {
            console.warning("No value or checked provided")
            completion(0)
            return
        }
        
        console.info(script)
        
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { result, error in
            if let result = result as? Int {
                // Result = number of filed fields
                if result > 0 {
                    // STOP EXECUTING
                }
            }
        }
    }
    completion(0)
    return
}
```

I want to ensure that once a selector successfully fills a field (or multiple fields), the function should stop processing and return early, avoiding unnecessary evaluations on the remaining selectors.

I've tried to use `DispatchSemaphore` but it won't work since `evaluateJavaScript` need to be executed in the main thread.

Any ideas on how to solve is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, the idea is to use [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup/) and make the loop run sequentially, since JS is a single threaded language, it should not be a problem and work like before. The code cannot run on the main thread because the wait() would block it, so it should run on a different thread that waits for the code that runs on the main thread to finish. This approach uses DispatchGroup but DispatchSemaphore should also work.

```
private func fillField(in webView: WKWebView, selectors: [String], value: String? = nil, checked: Bool? = nil, completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        for selector in selectors {
            let script: String
            if let value = value {
                script = String(format: "AutoFill.setValue(\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\')", selector, "value", value)
            } else if let checked = checked {
                script = String(format: "AutoFill.setValue(\'%@\', \'%@\', \'%@\')", selector, "checked", checked ? "true": "false")
            } else {
                console.warning("No value or checked provided")
                completion(0)
                return
            }

            console.info(script)

            dispatchGroup.enter()
            var shouldStopLoop = false

            webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { result, error in
                if let result = result as? Int {
                    // Result = number of filed fields
                    if result > 0 {
                        // STOP EXECUTING
                        shouldStopLoop = true
                    }
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }

            dispatchGroup.wait() // can set a timeout

            if shouldStopLoop {
                break // stop loop or call completion
            }
        }

        // maybe switch dispatchqueue before calling this
        completion(0)
    }
}
```